# Planet feed aggregator for django

Tags: rss, feeds, django, integration

We are looking for a way to integrate a feed aggregator (like a planet, which takes a set of rss/atom feeds and posts the latest *N* feed items) into a Django site. Ideally, the planet should integrate as part of a page of the site as a whole, rather than a standalone page like all other plants I've seen. We could use an iframe, but then style won't match. The best way might be something that just returns a raw list of last *N* feed items, which we then insert into a template.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to combine the feeds into a single feed, then simply display the latest n feed items with Python or JavaScript.

Mark Pilgrim's [feed parser](http://www.feedparser.org/) might help, as may the Django snippet to [parse an RSS feed here.](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/852/)